# Rails - custom action in controller - how to reference in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, link-to

I'm using a custom action to get the id of a project into the session, so that only relevant info for that project is shown in other areas. I've made a custom action in the projects controller, and am having trouble getting a link to work in the view to call that action. I just get an error saying "Couldn't find project without ID". I'm new to rails - I know it's probably an easy question, but help would be much appreciated, thanks!

View Code:

```
<%= link_to 'Select Project', :action => :select_project %>
```

Controller Code:

```
def select_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  session[:project_id] = @project.id
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    get :select_project
  end
end
```

Alternative routes code:

```
resources :projects do
  put 'select_project', on: :member
end
```

Comment: if it's relevant, the view code is the projects/show view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but I believe it is what you are looking for:

Routes:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    post :set_current
  end
end
```

this should create the following:

- Endpoint: /projects/:id/set_current POST
- Helper: set_current_project_path

Controller

```
def set_current
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  session[:project_id] = project.id
  redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Current project set to #{project.name}"
end
```

Views

```
# index / erb tags excluded for simplicity 
@projects.each do |project|
  link_to 'Select Project', set_current_project_path(project), :method => :post
end

# show
<%= link_to 'Select Project', set_current_project_path(@project), :method => :post %>
```

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Note also the use of 'post' instead of 'get', since we are changing the state of an object (session)
it is preferred to use a post not a get, otherwise users might pull up an old get request in the address bar
of their browser and set their session to a project unknowingly.

like `varatis` said - use `rake routes` or `CONTROLLER=projects rake routes` to help with determining what your route/path helpers look like and what http verbs they are expecting

---

> And is there a reason why it's project not @project in the controller

The @project creates an instance variable; in a rails controller instance variables are made available to the views. This set_current action will never render a view, so no reason to make an instance variable out of it.

---

> How come you have to set it to member and not collection in the routes

any action where you want to reference `params[:id]` should be a member route, an alternative would be to leave it as a collection route and pass `params[:project_id]` and pass that in all of your link_to calls, but in this case member makes more sense.

I believe `resources :projects` is a short cut for this break down

```
member do
  get :show
  get :edit
  put :update      
  delete :destroy
end
collection do
  get :index
  get :new
  post :create
end
```

hopefully that clarifies your questions some?

Comment: That's got it, thanks so much. How come you have to set it to member and not collection in the routes? And is there a reason why it's project not @project in the controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the route generated would be `select_project_projects_path`.

Link:

`<%= link_to 'Select Project', select_project_projects_path %>`

For future reference, run `rake routes` to see the automatic route helpers generated by Rails.

Comment: Woops -- reversed it. I think the edit I just made should work.

Comment: That gives me the error: undefined local variable or method `project_select_project_path', will try the rake routes, thanks

Comment: @EmilyTwist It's `projects_select_project_path`. You missed an 's'. And mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong one. Tried both just in case - didn't work. Will try rake routes in a bit, and mark as answered then, thanks!

Comment: @EmilyTwist Ah sorry. My original answer was actually the right one -- `select_project_projects_path`. Will my edit answer to correspond to the correct solution.

Comment: Ok - still getting the 'Couldn't find Project without an ID' error though - will rake routes, thanks for help!

Comment: I've done the rake routes and you're right about the path you're suggesting. I don't understand why, but it appears as if the id of the project isn't getting passed - I don't know why as I'm accessing it from url.com/projects/1 - any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you want to use member, not collection in your route, if you are interested in `params[:id]` containing the project id value and link_to needs to pass that value along `<%= link_to 'Select Project', select_project_projects_path(project) %>`

Comment: Hi, I've added the routes code that I've tried, it's now saying: undefined local variable or method `select_project_projects_path' - or if I add (project) after the projects_path, it's saying that is undefined. Any ideas why? Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you looping on projects and building multiple links? Or is this show, then pass @project to the path helper method